# Displaying Play/Pause Button in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I want to implement the show/hide feature of the play and pause buttons on a list of tracks in angular 7. I originally got this feature partially working using angular animation, but my method would change the state of all buttons in my list instead of a single item. I've also tried using ngClass but couldn't seem to get it working right.

Below is my latest efforts. Please help me.

```
 <mat-card class="track-box" *ngFor="let track of tracks" cdkDrag>
      <div class="custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>

      <span>

        <mat-icon  
        class="play-button md-48"
        [ngClass]="{'show' : track === selectedTrack}"
        (click)="toggle(track)"
        > play_circle_outline</mat-icon>

        <mat-icon 
        class="pause-button md-48" 
        [class.selected2]="track === selectedTrack"
        (click)="toggle(track)"
        >pause_circle_outline</mat-icon>  

      </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to disagree with @Tomato 's answer, as per my comment on his answer.

However, what I would recommend is using [Angular's `NgClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) which is similar to `ngIf`. But here's the catch.
When it comes to `ngIf`, you're creating 2 components, hiding one and showing the other, and doing that operation over and over again. Which is not the best code practice.

However, in the case of `ngClass`, you're creating one component and 2 separate SCSS classes for the same component. Whenever a certain condition is satisfied, one SCSS Class gets applied, and so forth.

- HTML File

  ```
    <span>
      <button
      class="play-pause-button"
      [ngClass]="toggle(track)"></button>
    </span>
  ```
- TS File

```
export class Component {

    let isPlay = false;

    public toggle(track: string) {
        this.isPlay = !this.isPlay;
        this.isPlay ? return 'play-button'; : return 'pause-button'
    }

}
```

That way, the `toggle()` function will return a `SCSS` class name based on the current status of the button itself.

Comment: I appreciate the help but this solution currently ignores the use of Angular Material icons

Answer (score -1):

**Using ngClass**

You could change the shown button icon by using `ngClass` as following:

```
<mat-card class="track-box" *ngFor="let track of tracks" cdkDrag>
      <div class="custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>

      <span>
        <mat-icon  
        class="md-48"
        [ngClass]="{'play-button' : track != selectedTrack,
            'pause-button' : track === selectedTrack}"
        (click)="toggle(track)">Some output here</mat-icon>

      </span>
</mat-card>
```

**Using ngIf**

You could maybe use an `ngIf` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)) to show/hide the buttons, though as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2918731/chris) pointed out, this creates two elements for every track in your list and could cause performance issues on a very huge list.

```
<mat-card class="track-box" *ngFor="let track of tracks" cdkDrag>
      <div class="custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder></div>

      <span>
        <mat-icon  
        class="play-button md-48"
        *ngIf="track != selectedTrack"
        (click)="toggle(track)">play_circle_outline</mat-icon>

        <mat-icon 
        class="pause-button md-48" 
        *ngIf="track === selectedTrack"
        (click)="toggle(track)">pause_circle_outline</mat-icon>  

      </span>
</mat-card>
```

When your `selectedTrack` does not equal the track, show the *play-button*, if it is the same track, show the *pause-button*.

You could also use the *if-else-block* for this (from the docs):

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```

Comment: In the case where you want to use `ngIf`, you're already creating 2 buttons, hiding one and showing the other. Which might, not in this case obviously, cause performance issues and would not be considered as best practice.

Comment: @Chris I added an example on how to do it without ngIf and use ngClass. Hopes this improves the answer.